# MySQL, RoR issues on Snow Leopard

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, osx-snow-leopard

I feel I've gone through every post on this subject, and I'm still banging my head against the wall.

I am running...
**Mac OS 10.6.6**
**MySQL 5.1.4.4** (on MAMP) or (MySQL 5.5.8 in my /usr/ directory) both can be running and work fine
**Ruby 1.8.7** (2010-12-23 patchlevel 330) [i686-darwin10.6.0] (using RVM)
**Rails 2.2.2**
**Gem 1.4.2**
**MySQL gem 2.8.1** *(it says it's installed)*

When I fire up the RoR app I've been developing, the mongrel appears to load fine. When I try to bring up the app in my browser I get the following error...

/!\ FAILSAFE /!\  Thu Jan 20 19:46:07 -0500 2011
  Status: 500 Internal Server Error
  uninitialized constant MysqlCompat::MysqlRes

then what follows are a bunch of lines like...

```
/Users/PJ/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:442:in `load_missing_constant'
```

I feel I have tired every variation of the ARCHFLAGS solutions that have been previously suggested on other posts. None have worked.

I am using MAMP and RVM as I have done other uninstalls and re-installs of MySQL, Ruby, Rails and various gems in attempts from other suggested solutions.

The app worked fine prior to my update to Snow Leopard. I am not a very sophisticated developer type, so I apologize in advance for being, well, not the brightest.

Comment: Why are you using Mongrel instead of WEBrick? Seems like causing more issues than it's worth.

Comment: I have the same issue with webrick, I like mongrel as it shows the log output in the terminal window.

Answer (score 0):

Try this AFTER making sure that Xcode is installed on your system.

gem uninstall mysql

export ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64" ; gem install --no-rdoc --
no-ri mysql -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local --with-mysql-config=/usr/
local/mysql/bin/mysql_config

Comment: should I uninstall Xcode, and re-install it? I have Xcode Version 3.2 64 bit installed.

Comment: i think there's a minor syntax error in what you wrote... there's a space between "--" and "no-ri" that was causing an error (no named gem in install command). after removing the space i got a permission error. after adding "sudo" to the "gem install" part i got a different error from an extra space in the directory path. It then installed.

Comment: even though it is showing that the mysql gem is installed. she still no work.

Comment: FYI, MAMP path for MySQL is /Applications/MAMP/Library, not /usr/local

Answer (score 0):

I coudn't ever seem to get the 2.8.1 mysql gem to work.
I downgraded it to the 2.7 version which led to a series of new errors (a DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH error), but it was eventually figured out and I am up and running again.